# Is it thread-safe to run multiple CommandLineRunner at same time via Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an old application (simple Java files starting from `main()` method) that is called by 4-5 autosys jobs all at same time passing different arguments.

Now, I have refactored this app to use spring boot CommandLineRunner. I changed only starting file to use spring boot to upgrade it.

Question: will this create any problem if my autosys job call this app 5 times at the same time passing different params ? Any issue with conflict of thread execution or object or any other?

I could not find my answer anywhere..though As far I know, all these 5 calls should create different JVM and execute the spring bean from CommandLineRunner. They should be treated all separate...

The call from autosys is simple
“`Java -jar javaApp.jar arg1 arg2`”

need your expertise suggestion.
Quick help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are sure you haven't done anything that will cause multiple instances to impact each other (changing shared resources?) then in theory they shouldn't impact each other. Of coures if they use a lot of RAM or disk (for temporaries), or more CPU than the machine can provide they might impact each other, but not in a way that can't be fixed by fixing the bottleneck.

Comment: Ya makes sense to me. For sure they all are not resource intensive.    I think each commandlinerunner when called should execute In It’s JVM (separate memory) and hence the objects in spring  containers should be separate. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you have created different CommandLineRunner classes in your Spring app, then Spring runs them sequentially in the main thread. No additional threads are involved.  The runners are run as just about the last step in the initialization of the app.  I happen to know this because it recently mattered to what I was doing, and so I looked at the source code.

To see this all for yourself, all you have to do is put a breakpoint at the start of one of your runners, and then look up the call stack.  You'll see the loop over the runners directly above you, and you'll see that the bottom of the stack contains your app's `main()`. Unlike many adventures into the Spring source code, this one was very simple.  I recommend you do this if you can just to see how remarkably simple it is.

The above being the case, it sounds like there's no real difference between what you have with Spring and what you had before...other than, of course, changes you've made yourself to your logic.  Spring doesn't add any complexity here.

As @MrR says, the only issue you might have is with contention for external resources if you're running multiple copies of your app at the same time.  But you would have had those with the old code as well.  Spring doesn't introduce anything new here either.